# Generate unique 10-digit number

Tags: mysql, numbers, unique

I want to generate customer ids for invoices and thus don't want to start counting from 1 for obvious reasons. In MySQL can you generate a random number that is unique?

I know about the RAND() function, but it does not guarantee uniqueness. What's the right approach for this?

Doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO test (number) VALUES (FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 9999999999)));
```

PS: Server side I'm using PHP and generate invoices using FPDF.

Comment: What's the obvious reason here?  Is it that invoices would somehow be viewable if you guessed the next id, or spoofable in some way? If that's the case, you have a different issue, and need to make sure that anyone viewing an invoice is authorized to do so. In lieu of that, I would look a using the UUID function (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid), although that seems like major overkill.

Comment: No, actually I'm not considering anything to do with spoofing etc. It's more that the company is a start-up and they don't wish to reveal that you are their first customer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column and seed the value at 10 digits. You could have it be the only column in the table, like below, or more practically seed your invoice table id.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id bigint unsigned not null auto_increment,
  primary key(id),
  auto_increment=1000000000
);
```

Comment: I like the idea, but the customer would still see an 1000000001 and know it was the first invoice ;-) Maybe I should pick a random number and go from there.

Comment: Fair enough. You'd have to pre-populate this table and mark rows as *used* then. But obviously there is a limitation to this solution.

Comment: I now changed to auto_increment value to sth crazy, hoping that no one will ever notice they are the first customer :-) Thanks for your help! +1

Comment: Jason, I think Frank meant a random _starting_ value, using your solution, rather than a random value every time.

Comment: I see. Then what Frank did should be fine - start the seed at a random 10 digit number and auto increment from there. In that case, I feel this is the appropriate solution as it is more robust than a pre-populated table of keys.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the reasons aren't that obvious unless it's simply that you don't want your customers to know there are so few that they all have one-digit IDs :-)

As an aside, the customer ID is usually generated when adding a *customer* rather than doing an invoice. If you meant an invoice number, that's different, but the reasoning will be the same.

Either populate the table with a dummy entry with a suitable lower ID (314159 for example) then use something like:

```
insert into test (number) select max(number)+1 from test
```

or use an auto incrementing key with a suitable starting value (again, this value is up to you but you should choose something relatively "non-round").

I've sometimes used the former for situations where I want total control over what values are assigned (including the ability to easily change them) but a more robust solution would probably be the auto-increment one.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE my_invoice_table auto_increment=1000000001
```

Incrementing invoice numbers are fine - they only have to be unique, not random.